# How to show a form on startup if there is data found in database in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is if for example a user has registered or saved data in the database they will be automatically redirected to a certain form on startup...

Here is the code I've tried so far and it it is not working according to how I want it to be...

In Form1:

```
// I declared the rowcounts as public
public int rowcounts;

public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection connCount = locald.DB.GetSqlConnection();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new 
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = connCount;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.CommandText = @"countval";
        rowcounts = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
        label1.Text = rowcounts.ToString();
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
{
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1 f1 = new Form1();

        if (f1.rowcounts == 0)   
        {
            Application.Run(new Form2());    // if database has no records
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
}
```

I created a class DB.cs for connection

```
public class DB
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["locald.Properties.Settings.localdConnectionString"].ToString();

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connStr);
            sb.ApplicationName = ApplicationName ?? sb.ApplicationName;
            sb.ConnectTimeout = (ConnectionTimeout > 0) ? ConnectionTimeout : sb.ConnectTimeout;

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public static int ConnectionTimeout { get; set; }

    public static SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        cnn.Open();
        return cnn;
    }
}
```

The problem is even if the database has or without data it would still show the Form1 on startup. What I want is if the database has data it would automatically be redirected to the Form1 and if it has not then it will be in Form2 on startup...

Please help.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: what is f1 in your main? theres no mention of it, and your db code is in form1 so you had to have opened it to do your test... looks like confused logic to me

Comment: Oh sorry I just forgot to write it in my question
It is for initializing the form1 
Form f1 = new Form1

Comment: no wonder your programs not working :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

defects in your program are,

what is f1 ?
i am seeing that you have coded SQL functions in Form1.cs.

why don't you perform all the SQL operations on program.cs
and redirect to the form as per your query result.

follow as below,

**program.cs**

```
 static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            int rowcounts = 0;

            SqlConnection connCount = locald.DB.GetSqlConnection();
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand com = new 
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            com.Connection = connCount;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = @"countval";
            rowcounts = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());


            if (rowcounts == 0){
                Application.Run(new Form2()); //if database has no records
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
private void Form1_Load()
{

}
```

Comment: sorry the f1 is from Form1 f1 = new Form1(); I just forgot to put it when I first posted the question..

Comment: No worries,
you can simply achieve that just move all your code from Form1_Load() to program.cs and load the form as per SQL result

Comment: When I do that, do I have to create a function in program.cs where I will put my codes from form1? or just put it all in static void main of program.cs??

Sorry I'm kinda new to C#.net

Comment: updated my answer, move the codes from form1_load() to the program.cs, you don't need to create methods for this since this is not going to get reused anywhere, we can directly add them to the static class itself.

Comment: it is working fine now. thanks...

But just one question I want to show the count value of database in my label in form1 how can I do that? do I have to declare my rowcount variable in program.cs as public int rowcount and call it in form1 in order to show my count value?? Is that possible?

Comment: never mind about my last question, I done it now... And thanks for helping.. GOD BLESS :)

Comment: you are most welcome, you don't really need to create public variable, you can pass that through constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post it as a comment, but can't comment with low reputation...
First of all, you're missing "if" in your Program.cs (I believe it's not the real problem, or is it?)

Secondly, you can try to call "Close" on form1 if you don't want it to show, right in its "Initialize", just as an easy solution.

Like that:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //...
            //Your code
            //...

            // If no data
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: sorry there is already an "if" in my actual code, I just have a typing error when I posted the question :)